# I'm new to programming and would like to know how to create a calculator using ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is my current code for the calculator but I don't know how to make the two numbers perform the operation.

```
#calculator
#ask the user for the first number
puts "Please select your first number"
#store num_1 inside a variable
num_1 = gets.chomp.to_i
#spit back the number
puts "#{num_1}"
#ask the user what order of operation they want to use
puts "would you like to add, subtract, multiply, or divide this number?"
#store the order of operation inside a variable
operation = gets.chomp.to_i
#ask the user for a second number
puts "please select a second number to #{operation}"
#store num_2 inside a variable
num_2 = gets.chomp.to_i
#perform the task and spit out a number
answer = num_1 operation num_2
#spit out the number
puts "your answer for #{num_1} #{operation} #{num_2} = #{answer}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there. In your case you need to call `public_send` method to perform the desired operation.

```
answer = num_1.public_send operation, num_2
```

Note: `operation = gets.chomp.to_i` should be `operation = gets.chomp`.

As per your code add, subtract, multiply, or divide will be `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` respectively. Now as you are using `gest` method to take those as an input, you will be getting `'+'`, `'-'` etc after *chomping*. Now if you call `String#to_i` method on those `"+"`, `"-"` etc, as per the documentation,

> If there is not a valid number at the start of `str`, `0` is returned.

Read about [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-public_send).